# Visual studio 2013 builds every time unnecessarily and is slow

Tags: vb.net, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio profession 2013. .NET framework installed 4.5.

My Visual studio is giving me some problems. When i run it builds every single time.Takes up a good 2 minutes to build. If i change a class then i understand it should build, but not every time i make a change to .aspx or .aspx.vb page. it did not work this way for Visual studio 2012. Is there any setting I am not seeing?Language being built in is VB. Should i change any setting value? Is there any IIS express value I need to set?
 If you need more info,please ask.Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue even after trying the recommedation in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow

Comment: @osiris355. No. I tried that option on that thread. No result. I have other projects in VS 2013 they work just fine. Just this one project.

Answer (score 4):

Un-check:

Tools > Options > Package Manager > General > Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio

It seems to have improved the build time.

Comment: from around 25 seconds I get to 3 seconds! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get some performance back I did the following three things. Obviously your mileage may vary.

1. Turn off the [Enable Edit and Continue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570202/1603799) feature
2. Turn off the [Browser Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712669/1603799) feature
3. Turn off [Hardware Acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20221470/1603799)