# Why is IIS exiting with code 0 whenever I preview in Chrome from Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-chrome

I started on a new [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) site yesterday with [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net); I am familiar with VB.NET but not ASP.NET.

My primary browser is Google Chrome, but when I attempt to 'emulate' (debug) the site, the debugger exits the local development server spawned by Visual Studio and as a result, Chrome can never load the website (since when it tries to the webserver isn't running). This can be seen easily by viewing Chrome and Visual Studio side-by-side; Visual Studio's status bar turns orange for a second or so then goes back to blue, and IIS exits with code `0`:

```
The program '[73048] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[73048] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

However this can be temporarily fixed by 'emulating' in Internet Explorer and then with Chrome again, but this fix must be applied on every reboot in order for it to work.

Why is this happening, and how can I properly debug in Chrome without the webserver exiting?

I read [How can I prevent Visual Studio 2013 from closing my IIS Express app when I end debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568762/how-can-i-prevent-visual-studio-2013-from-closing-my-iis-express-app-when-i-end) but however none of the solutions helped me in this respect, and that the issue is that Visual Studio seems to be closing `iisexpress.exe` when the debugging has started.

Chrome runs each tab in a separate process (sandboxing), so perhaps it could be that Visual Studio is expecting Chrome's 'base' PID when Chrome actually spawns an entirely new PID for the new tab created when the 'emulator' starts?

Is there any solution to this other than use Internet Explorer (or the 'fix') for debugging the site?

[I have recorded what's happening here, and I still find it odd that Internet Explorer is able to 'cure' the problem temporarily.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQKgpMPg6HM&feature=youtu.be)

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Windows 8.1 Pro (Media Centre Edition) and Chrome 40.0.2214.93 m.

Comment: hey, have you checked this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472682/asp-net-mvc5-iis-express-unable-to-debug-code-not-running

Comment: @Justcode Just did, and it appears to have worked, thanks :). Provide that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You can put it as an answer will help future visitors.

Comment: Reason for the sudden downvote?