# How can I prevent visual studio 2015 from closing IIS express app when end debug?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I've tried this answer posted for Visual Studio 2013.

[How can I prevent Visual Studio 2013 from closing my IIS Express app when I end debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568762/how-can-i-prevent-visual-studio-2013-from-closing-my-iis-express-app-when-i-end)

In Visual Studio 2015, it is bit different and didn't work for me.

How can I prevent closing Visual Studio 2015 `IIS` express app when I end the debug?

Answer (score 6):

[image]Does right click on the "project -> view -> view in browser" work for you needs? It starts iis express and keeps it running.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i don't see Project->view-> view in browser it has only project->view->view class diagram

Comment: @Mahesh I updated my answer with an image where "View in Browser" suppose to be.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still causes a headache where, if you start a regular F5 debug again, then stop it, you then have to to CTRL+F5 again. In 2013, I could start and stop a debug session and it would keep the IIS instance running. I still can't find answer for this change in 2015 to make it behave like 2013.

Comment: This is one of those things that worked better in VS2013 and now is a complete mess... Unless of course there is something that we are all unaware of...

Answer (score 4):

In VS 2015, go to Debug menu select Start Without Debugging.
It will run the web application without debugging. 
You can now make changes and rebuild project, then refresh your browser to see changes.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's what I do and it works in both VS 2015 and VS 2017.

1. In the Solution Explorer,  right click on the project
2. Go to Properties, then top the Web tab
3. In the Debuggers section, make sure "Enable Edit and Continue" is unchecked.

Start debug section, stop debug, and you should see that IIS Express server continues, i.e. does not get annoyingly shut down.